# Hidden droppables doesn't trigger over and out even after it becomes visible

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I would like to have top level droppable area and when the user start to drag some elements into this area, I want to split it on different sections (north, east, south and west etc.) and allow the user to drop at any of them.

what would be the best way to do this?

here is what I try to do:

**HTML**

```
<div class='main_droppable_area'>
    <div class='drop_area north'></div>
    <div class='drop_area east'></div>
    <div class='drop_area south'></div>
    <div class='drop_area west'></div>
</div>
<div class='draggable_area'>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main_droppable_area {
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    right: 50px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
    position: absolute;
}

.drop_area {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
    background-color: #eff;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    display: none;
}

.drop_area.active {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}

.drop_area.north {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 50px;
}

.drop_area.south {
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 50px;
}

.drop_area.west {
    top: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}

.drop_area.east {
    top: 50px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}

.draggable_area {
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( '.draggable_area' ).draggable();

    $('.main_droppable_area').droppable({
        accept: '.draggable_area',
        over: function() {
            console.log('main_droppable_area - over');
            $('.drop_area').show();
        },
        out: function() {
            console.log('main_droppable_area - out');
            $('.drop_area').hide();
        }
    });

    $('.drop_area').droppable({
        accept: '.draggable_area',
        over: function() {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            console.log('drop_area - over');
        },
        out: function() {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            console.log('drop_area - out');
        }
    });
});
```

But unfortunately this code doesn't work all the time... for example it doesn't work if I try to drag item from outside the main droppable area.

However if I drag and drop the item into that area and start to drag it again it works.

Is something wrong with my code? here is my JSFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/pshenichnov/cfacrpbm/2/)

**UPDATE**

Thanks to T J for the solution... here is [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pshenichnov/cfacrpbm/3/) with the working example

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"it doesn't work"*..?

Comment: I can't get code for 'over' and 'out' working. Open the console and try to drag blue box into the droppable area. When you move over north/east/south/west areas it should catch over/out events but it doesn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hide the droppables using `display:none`, the element won't be rendered at all. Hence when a valid draggable starts dragging, it won't be *activated*, and the changes you make won't take place until a new drag is started *activating* the droppables.

One work around is to use `visibility:hidden` instead to hide your inner draggables so that the elements will be *rendered*, and dragging will *activate* droppables so that *over*, *out* etc function properly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.draggable_area').draggable();

  $('.main_droppable_area').droppable({
    accept: '.draggable_area',
    over: function() {
      console.log('main_droppable_area - over');
      $('.drop_area').removeClass("invisible");
    },
    out: function() {
      console.log('main_droppable_area - out');
      $('.drop_area').addClass("invisible");
    }
  });

  $('.drop_area').droppable({
    activate: function() {
      console.log("activated");
    },
    accept: '.draggable_area',
    over: function() {
      $(this).addClass('active');
      console.log('drop_area - over');
    },
    out: function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      console.log('drop_area - out');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.main_droppable_area {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
}
.drop_area {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  background-color: #eff;
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
.drop_area.active {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
.drop_area.north {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 50px;
}
.drop_area.south {
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 50px;
}
.drop_area.west {
  top: 50px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
.drop_area.east {
  top: 50px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
.draggable_area {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class='main_droppable_area'>
  <div class='drop_area north invisible'></div>
  <div class='drop_area east invisible'></div>
  <div class='drop_area south invisible'></div>
  <div class='drop_area west invisible'></div>
</div>
<div class='draggable_area'></div>
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks T J! I was thinking that it's related to the fact that the areas are hidden but didn't know how to resolve it... not it works!